# Setting up a small DHCP server for small network on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am trying to set up a DHCP server on a Windows 2003 machine for a small network. I have used this guide[http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/dhcp_server_windows_2003.html] to setup the DHCP server, windows is now showing me that this is now a configured role.

My question is there anything I need to do after the steps mentioned in guide. I have connected the server machine and the 3 machine i want to make a network with to a linksys router, all connetions are working but none of my machines are getting assigned an IP, I am also unable to ping the server machine.

Comment: Why deploy a new Server 2003 box this late in its lifecycle?  If at all possible, you shouldn't be using anything older than Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

- You may need to [authorize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759688%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the DHCP server if you haven't already
- If there's a DHCP server on the LinkSys router, you'll need to turn it off
- Make sure your server has a static IP address
- Ensure that you've [bound](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739653(WS.10).aspx) your DHCP server to the correct NIC
- Make sure your server's firewall is not set to block DHCP requests
- Issue an `ipconfig /renew` on one of your clients to force it to try and pick up an address from DHCP.